# Visual Studio 2015 trava quando digito "<" no Apache Cordova

Tags: html, apache-cordova, visual-studio-2015

Estou utilizando o Visual Studio 2015 para criar aplicações com o Apache Cordova, e toda vez que eu insiro o carácter de "<" (para abrir uma tag HTML) o software trava e fecha, sem motivo algum.

Já aconteceu com alguém? Sabem o motivo?

Answer (score 1):

De acordo com o seguinte **bug**: https://github.com/aspnet/Tooling/issues/112

O problema ocorre por falta de compatibilidade entre o editor HTML ou razor view e o cordova.

**Possiveis soluções**:

1. Atualize para a versão **2015.1** ([link](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/vs2015-update1-vs.aspx))
2. Desistalar o **TypeScript**.
3. Trocar o 'src' do `<script>`

   ```
   <script src="1.1.1/js/ionic.bundle.min.js"></script>
   ```

   para

   ```
   <script src="http://code.ionicframework.com/1.1.1/js/ionic.bundle.min.js"></script>
   ```

Comment: Danilo, obrigado! Porém não deu certo nenhum dos três passos. Quando vou instalar a versão 2015.1 o botão não permite clicar, não achei o local que desistala o Type Script e não estou utilizando esse 'src'.

Comment: Tenho certeza que ao atualizar pro 2015.1 resolva...